# What can I do in this code to prompt an error when a negative number is used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

i was wondering what can I do to prompt an error when I input a negative number. I used a for loop for this program. What this program does, or at least its supposed to do, is to output the factor of any given number (if positive). But I am not sure how to make my code to prompt an error or at least keep asking for a number if the number that input is less or equal to 0.

I used the variable n as the number to input by the user.

I am really new to programming and I am eager to finish this program as soon as possible. Can you please assist?

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  using namespace std;


int main()
{
double n;
cout << "Welcome to this program... Hope you like it" << flush << endl;
do
{
    int i, fact = 1, n;
    cout << "Please enter a value for the variable " "n: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " is: " << fact << endl;
    cout << " Thanks for using this program... hope you liked it!" << endl;
} while (n >= 0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait. You have 2 `n`s. Best not to do this. It's legal since they are in different scopes, but it's source of confusion.

Comment: Consider drawing a picture of what you want the code to do. Then draw a picture of what the code does. Them move the code around until the picture of what the code does matches what the code should do.

Answer (score 0):

Commens in the code:

```
#include <iostream>

// it's best not to do using namespace std. It's a huge namespace

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to this program... Hope you like it\n";
    do
    {
        int i, fact = 1, n;
        std::cout << "Please enter a value for the variable " "n: ";
        std::cin >> n;

        // if std::cin is in a failed state then break out of the loop.
        if (std::cin.fail()) break;

        // added check if n<0. if n<0 ptint error on stderr
        if (n<0) {
            std::clog << "Error: you must supply a number equal to or greater than zero\n";
        } else { // if n>=0 
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            std::cout << "Factorial of " << n << " is: " << fact << "\n";
        }
    } while (true); // <- now always true 

    std::cout << "\nThanks for using this program... hope you liked it!\n";
    return 0;
}
```